# What's this setter error ("X" is not defined...) when using a property?

Tags: python, properties, setter

```
@property
def GetURLLabel(self):
    return self._URLLabel

# Setter methods
@URLLabel.setter
def SetURLLabel(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        self._URLLabel = value
    else:
        raise ValueError("Must be a string")
```

I get the error:

```
"URLLabel" is not defined
PylancereportUndefinedVariable
(function) URLLabel: Any
```

Here is the object code:

```
class SSLSite:
    def __init__(self, URLLabel, x, x, ...):
        self._URLLabel = URLLabel
```

I am working to set the value of the properties, and URLLabel is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 different names:

- `GetURLLabel` as the name of the getter method
- `SetURLLabel` as the name of the setter method
- `URLLabel` in the decorator of the setter method

The names must all be the same. If you want the name of the property to be `URLLabel`, you must define two methods called `URLLabel`, the first one decorated with `@property` and the second one decorated with `@URLLabel.setter`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) you need to declare `@property` before of `setter`. Try do this:

```
class SSLSite:
    def __init__(self, URLLabel, x, y):
        self._URLLabel = URLLabel

    @property
    def URLLabel(self):
        return self._URLLabel

    @URLLabel.setter
    def URLLabel(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            self._URLLabel = value
        else:
            raise ValueError("Must be a string")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe my issue was that I was using the method name "GetURLLabel". Once I dropped the Get from method name it worked great. Thank you, guys!  I apreciate your responses, friends!